# XCTest - UI Testing with XCUIElement using pinch gesture on custom coordinates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xctest

Let's say I've an app with an UI which looks kind of like the image below:

[image: UI to test]

Let's also say the blue view behaves like a map and the other colors are other interactable views.

I need to do a XCTest where I need to "zoom out" on that blue view which I tired with [pinchWithScale](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/1618669-pinchwithscale?language=objc):

```
[blueView pinchWithScale:0.5 velocity:-1];
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work because one of the red views or the violet view (which overlaps the blue view a tiny bit for shadow and corner reasons) gets triggered instead of a `pinch` gesture on the blue view.

I saw that I can get [coordinateWithNormalizedOffset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/1500960-coordinatewithnormalizedoffset?language=objc) (similar like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301798/replicate-pull-to-refresh-in-xctest-ui-testing)) of a view by using the method:

```
- (XCUICoordinate *)coordinateWithNormalizedOffset:(CGVector)normalizedOffset;
```

which would allow me to use not the whole blue view to perform a "zoom out" gesture by:

```
XCUICoordinate* blueViewInset = [blueView coordinateWithNormalizedOffset:
                                 CGVectorMake(0.2f, 0.2f)];
```

but the [XCUICoordinate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuicoordinate?language=objc) object `blueViewInset` doesn't support pinch gestures.

Hence how can I perform a pinch gesture to "zoom out" on a XCUIElement with coordinates not at the border of the view?

I'm also wondering if there is a way to create an **extension to XCUIElement** with a **custom pinch** gesture? I would appreciate any hints on that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that I *can (but don't want to)* add another **empty view on top** of my `blueView` with constraints to **half of the size** of it (see yellowish rectangle in the illustration below). This works for all my cases so far because no other view overlaps that far. It looks something like this:

[image: UI with emtpy view for pinch gestures]

Executing a `pinchWithScale` on that empty view works and actually pinches the `blueView`.

This is a very ugly solution, since I've to add a view which is solely for UI testing.

If anyone has a hint on how to remove it for the release build let me know.

**Update**

I made a build step running a script which adds this view only when executing the UI automation test target. After the execution the source control (e.g. git reset HEAD~) is used to undo the added view.